# Bundler Incompatible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, windows-10-desktop

I have installed latest version for ruby and rails but test install is giving error . Please could you help me resolve this issue im using windows 10

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (=4.2.5.1)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Comment: remove gemfile.lock & do bundle install again.

Comment: this risks other things breaking as every gem will potentially get upgraded. A lot of change possible. If removing gemfile.lock, keep a copy and you can choose to revert after investigating

Answer (score 0):

Do as advised by bundler:

```
bundle update
bundle
```